# How to make a shrink-to-fit container with max-height and scrollbars in the content area?

Tags: html, css, scroll, containers

I am trying to achieve something like a regular windows' window with a title and a scrollable content area. The `.frame` shrinks to fit its variable size content and is limited only by `max-width`/`max-height`:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="content scrollable">content of variable width/height</div>
</div>
```

So, basically, no outer `width`/`height` are set, the `.frame` `width`/`height` is limited just by `max-width`, `max-height`, other than that the `.frame` shrinks to fit its content.
The result will look like just a regular windows window with a titlebar and variable `width`/`height` content, which should scroll if the frame's `height`/`width` exceeds some max values.

How can it be done in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.frame
{
max-width: 400px;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8vUP/)

Comment: WOW! I did not even think about such a crazy solution as adding a display:fixed; to the .title! Thank you! The CSS is such a crazy world!!!

Comment: Not "display: fixed" but "position: fixed"

Comment: yes, sorry, of course, got tired after trying to find a solution for several hours.

Comment: No probs mate. Happens to the best of us!